# Time dilation: linear or exponential or other?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, speed-of-light, time, time-dilation

As you near the speed of light, time slows for you relative to the world around you. So you would be traveling at more than one hour per hour. Is the rate of time slowing for you linear or exponential or another type of change? Can anyone explain? Am I thnking about this whole concept of time dilation wrong?

Comment: "Time", or better "time perception" doesn't change, at all. What changes is the difference between the time measurements between two observers who are moving relative to each other.

Comment: It seems you're familiar with [time dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation), so does the relation between $dt$ as you'd measure it and $d\tau$ as someone else would appear linear or exponential?

Answer (score 2):

> **Time dilation: linear or exponential or other?**

**Other**

---

$$\Delta t' = \gamma\Delta t = \frac{\Delta t}{\sqrt{1 - \frac {v^2}{c^2}}}$$

---

Lorentz factor $\gamma$ as a function of speed (in natural units where $c=1$)

[image]
[<sup>- Image by Zayani CC BY-SA 3.0</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Time_dilation.svg)